# How to read a string value from a dict that has special character forwardslash in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I have an input coming as dict and assigned it to variable 'var_1'

input:

```
{
    "key_1":"value_1",
    "key_2":"12345/6789-0ab1"
}
```

Assigning input to a variable

```
var_1 = input()
```

When I am trying to read 'key_2' value from 'var_1' getting error **'string indices must be integers'**.

Code is running success in local, but after deployment seeing above error at below line of code, reading the string value.

```
var_2 = var_1["key_2"]
```

Expected outcome:
I want the exact value of 'key_2' from var_1 to be assigned to var_2.

Tried below solutions and no luck:

1. Assigning the input dict to string and reading using json.loads().
2. r(var_1["key_2"])
3. rep(var_1["key_2"])
4. rf(var_1["key_2"])
5. Tried multiple other solutions and none working fine.

Comment: Please provide more details. Most likely your input comes as a string, not a dict as you think.

Comment: @matszwecja Updated question. Please recheck. Input is coming as a valid json, which is provided in the Input section

Comment: There is no backslash in the key. But if you get the error `string indices must be integers` when you do `dict_object["key_2"]` then obviously `dict_obj` is not a dictionary but a string. It seems as some part of your full code not show here overwrites the dictionary.

Comment: @Matthias "key_2" : "12345/6789-0ab1" if you check this, 'key_2' has a backslash in it.

Comment: I only see an underscore (`_`). A backslash looks like this (`\\`). An underscore has no special meaning.

Comment: Your question might be misleading. How exactly do you define `dict_obj`? I have a feeling that it's not the code you showed in the codeblock starting with `dict_obj = { ...`. If you do something like `dict_obj = input()` that would explain the problem.

Comment: I updated the question as per your suggestions. Thanks for pointing the corrections.
I am getting forward-slash in the request and want to read that string as is. @Matthias

Comment: @Nani valid JSON **is** a string, not a dictionary. They look similiar, but they are not the same.

Comment: In order to convert json to an actual dictionary, you can use `json.loads`.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a string in JSON format you can use `json.loads` to create a Python datastructure from it.

```
import json

value = """
{
    "key_1":"value_1",
    "key_2":"12345/6789-0ab1"
}"""

dict_obj = json.loads(value)

print(dict_obj["key_2"])
```

Comment: my input is a valid Json coming as a dict and not as a string.

Comment: But ... but ... if you have data in JSON format it is text. A string. Even according to the error message in your question you have a string. You can't say that you have JSON as a dictionary. That makes no sense. JSON may contain the representation of a dictionary but JSON data is text.